# Avoid Multiple Users to Use Excel at once on cloud

Tags: excel, vba, google-drive-shared-drive

I have an Excel file on googleDrive shared with many people, i've set a Login that prompts when someone opens the file, basically it hides all sheets but the login one (which is protected) and also protects the Workbook so sheets can't be unhidden, on a Config sheet theres a table with usernames and passwords and if credentials are correct i use VBA to unhide corresponding sheets based on user type and i save the file (which causes it to get updated for everyone in the cloud).

Id like to avoid two users using same file at once as it can cause data corruption, for that im using a `Private Sub Workbook_Open()` that checks and if there's a username in Login form it closes the application, the problem is when it closes it runs the `Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)` which is meant to erase the login form when a user actually closes the file manually, im wondering if there's a way to bypass that event when explicitly indicated?

Iv tried putting this in `Private Sub Workbook_Open()`:

```
Dim usr As String

usr = Worksheets("Login").Range("B3").Value

If usr <> "" Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.Quit
End If
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I Edited the code above and it worked:

```
Dim usr As String

usr = Worksheets("Login").Range("B3").Value

If usr <> "" Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.Quit
    Exit Sub
End If
```